# Method exist in SQL Server does not work correctly with C# parameters @XPath in a request

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml

The method exist for XML object does not work correctly with parameter in SQL request from .NET backend side. In my case, I try to send `@XPath` parameter to the request and put whole this one through exist method to select all XML items according to this XPath but as result, I get all non-filtered by these XPath XML from a table.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1000) ord.TrackingID, ord.DateCreate, ord.OrderType, ord.Error_Description, ord.Response, ord.Request
                     FROM FilteredByXPath AS ord
                     WHERE (ord.Request.exist(''sql:variable("@XPath")'') = 1)',
                   N'@TrackingID nvarchar(4000),@ShowAutotestCases bit,@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@InputOrderSource nvarchar(1),@Agency int, @XPath nvarchar(max)',
                     @TrackingID=NULL,@ShowAutotestCases=0,@DateFrom='1753-01-01 00:00:00',@DateTo='9999-12-31 23:59:59.997',@InputOrderSource=N'%',@Agency=0, @XPath=N'//*[text() = "10:33:34.9375000-05:00"]'
```

Following the exist description I think the ''sql:variable("@XPath")'' returns all time nonempty result and all XML is suitable.

The variants which work well are

```
WHERE ord.Request.exist(''//*[text() = sql:variable("@XPath")]'') = 1
```

or

```
WHERE ord.Request.exist(''//*[text() = "10:33:34.9375000-05:00"]'') = 1
```

As we see the two variants well when we use XPath as a string directly or `@XPath` parameter into XQuery.

The question how can I use `@XPath` parameter as a full XQuery expression like in first variant that does not work.

```
WHERE (ord.Request.exist(''sql:variable("@XPath")'') = 1)
```

Comment: Why are you using `sp_executesql` at all here? The fact you are using it would imply you have dynamic SQL, but you don't. You also pass a bunch of variables/parameters (such as `@TrackingID` and `@DateFrom`) but never actually use them.

Comment: T-SQL is very picky and has many non-orthogonal features that can surprise people. If [exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) says that it accepts a *literal string*, then that's what it accepts. You cannot use an *expression that computes a string*, you cannot use a *string variable*.

Comment: @Larnu I put here sp-executesql because I have this expression on SQL side from .Net side and this expression is only part of full one.